while loop only iterating only once
I have a function that check for zeroes in a matrix (list of lists) and a program that i want it to run until there are no zeroes in my matrix but the while loop runs only once can anybody explain why?
here's my code in python.
def not_solved(matrix):
    has0 = bool
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                has0 = True
            else:
                has0 = False
    return has0


matrix1 = [[-1, -2, 0], [-1, -2, 0], [-1, -2, 0]]
#matrix0 = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

while not_solved(matrix1):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if matrix1[i][j] <= 0:
                matrix1[i][j] += 1
           

print(matrix1)

i tried running it with the list
matrix1 = [[-1, -2, 0], [-1, -2, 0], [-1, -2, 0]]

and it returns one try of the for loop
[[0, -1, 1], [0, -1, 1], [0, -1, 1]]

but i was expecting
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]


not_solved() should return True immediately when it sees a zero, instead of continuing to run and possibly setting has0 back to False if a later element is nonzero.

Your function is only really checking the last element of the matrix. It throws away all its tests of all the preceding elements.
The reason that the while loop runs only once is that on entry, the last element is 0 which causes the loop to enter. The next iteration, the last element is 1 which fools your loop into thinking that there are no zeroes left anywhere.
This is a job for the any() function:
def not_solved(matrix):
    return any(matrix[i][j] == 0 for i in range(3) for j in range(3))


I assume that your question is this. The function not_solved checks if there is any 0 present in the given matrix. If any zero is present, the second function starts, The second function checks if any elements of the matrix is less than or equal to zero. If so, it adds 1 and the iteration continues till all the negative numbers and zero becomes 1.
Though there are easier ways possible, I understand that the OP wants to know how the iteration works. So for the OP to understand the iteration in an easy manner, I've given the solution the same way the OP expexts.
def not_solved(matrix):
    has0  =  False
    for x in matrix:
        for y in x:
            if y == 0:
                has0 = True
                break
    return has0

def solved(matrix): 
    if not_solved(matrix):   
        for i in range(3):
            j = 0
            while j < 3:
                if matrix[i][j] <= 0:
                    matrix[i][j] += 1
                
                    j = j - 1 
                    # the above condition is important which continues the the iteration till the value becomes 1 
                j += 1
        
    return matrix

matrix1 = [[-1, -2, 0], [-1, -2, 0], [-1, -2, 0]]
r = solved(matrix1)
print(r) #Output: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]


Finding a non-zero shouldn't set has0 = False, because you still have seen a zero before, as the last value is 1 after one iteration, it stops
The minimal modification is
def not_solved(matrix):
    has0 = False
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                has0 = True
    return has0

But you can improve it like this
def not_solved(matrix):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                return True
    return False

